# react-table and react-hook-form & external api call data not displaying

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form, react-table

I have my react JS app broken up into separate components, a App component that is the main landing page,  a Form component containing my react-form and a Table component containing my table.

Whenever I submit the form, I get an error that says cannont read properties of undefined. For some reason it looks like state data is not getting passed into the useTable hook? I am able to console log the "Data" and I can see the data results in the conosle. Im not sure what Im missing here.

Please see the following:

```
//app.jsx
export const App = (props) => {

const [data, setData] = useState('')

const formData = (data) => {
        setData(data);
    };

return (
<Form   formToData = {formData}

/>

<Table data= {data} /> 
}
```

```
\\ Table.jsx

export const Table = ({data}) => {

 const dataColumns =  [

    {
      Header: "ID",
      accessor: "id",
    },
    {
      Header: "Full Address",
      accessor: "full_address",
    },
    {
      Header: "firstname",
      accessor: "First Name",
    },
    {
      Header: "lastname",
      accessor: "Last Name",
    },
    {
  

  ]

const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow} = useTable({dataColumns, data: data})


return (

            <table {...getTableProps()}>
              <thead>
                {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
                  <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                    {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                      <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render('Header')}</th>
                    ))}
                  </tr>
                ))}
              </thead>
               <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
                {rows.map((row) => {
                  prepareRow(row);
                  return (
                    <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                      {row.cells.map((cell) => (
                        <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                      ))}
                    </tr>
                  )
                })}
              </tbody> 
             </table> 
)
}
```

```
\\Form.jsx
export const Form = ({ formToData } ) => {
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    reset,
    formState: { errors },
    register,
    watch,
    setValue
  } = useForm();

const handleApiCall = async (formData) => {
try {
request = await axios.post ( 'http://www.api.com', data)
formToData (queryResponse.data);
} catch (error) { console.log(error}}}

return (
   <div
      style={{
        width: "100%",
      }}
    >
      <Grid container justifyContent="center">
        <Grid item className="gridItem">
          <Text name={"lastName"} control={control} label={"Last Name"}  />
        </Grid>

        <Grid item className="gridItem">
          <Text name={"firstName"} control={control} label={"First Name"}  />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item className="gridItem">
          <Text name={"full_address"} control={control} label={"Address"}  />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item className="gridItem">
          <Text name={"ID"} control={control} label={"ID"}  />
        </Grid>
<Box display="flex" justifyContent="space-between">
            <Button
              onClick={ handleSubmit(handleApiCall)}  
              variant={"contained"}
              className="button"
              color="success"
              size="large"
            >
              Submit
            </Button
)}
```

any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated